# Show only checked nodes and parents of it in jstree

Tags: jstree

I have to show only selected nodes and parents, and hide rest nodes.

There is no get_unchecked in current documentation. My json format is huge so taking it in string and formatting and reloading tree will be inefficient.

Is there a way to get all unchecked nodes and hide it?
if there is i can check all parent node of current checked node and then just hide all unchecked nodes, but i cannot find any method to retrive all unchecked nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work around for the question i made.

```
$('#jstree_demo_div').on('loaded.jstree', function(e, data) {
  console.log("loaded");
  checked_ids = $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree('get_selected', true);
  $("#jstree_demo_div").jstree('select_all');
  $.each(checked_ids, function(index, value) {
    $("#jstree_demo_div").jstree('deselect_node', value);
    uiParentsShow(value);
  });
  checked_ids = $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree('get_selected', true);
  $.each(checked_ids, function(index, value) {
    $("#jstree_demo_div").jstree('hide_node', value);

  });
});

function uiParentsShow(node) {
  try {
    var parent = $("#jstree_demo_div").jstree('get_parent', node);
    $("#jstree_demo_div").jstree('deselect_node', parent);
    if (parent != '#') {
      uiParentsShow1(parent);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error in uiGetParents' + err);
  }
}
```

Steps:

- Step 1: Selecting All the elements
- Step 2: Deselecting the checked node and the parent of checked node
- Step 3: Hide Selected Nodes

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by:

1. getting all selected nodes along with the parents
2. going over all nodes and seeing if a node is not selected, then hiding it

Check code below and demo - [codepen](http://codepen.io/ermakovnikolay/pen/ZWWQoJ?editors=1111).

```
var $tree = $("#myTree").jstree(),
    nodesSelected = $('#myTree').jstree('get_checked', true),
    nodeIdsToStay = [];

nodesSelected.forEach(function(node) {
    var path = $tree.get_path(node, false, true);
    path.forEach(function(n) {
        if (nodeIdsToStay.indexOf(n) === -1) {
            nodeIdsToStay.push(n);
        }
    })
})

$('#myTree').find('li').each(function() {
    if (nodeIdsToStay.indexOf(this.id) === -1) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: Not working for my dataset. its realy long, How can i send u the data set

Comment: It is showing some sibling nodes. i can mail u the jsondata if u want, and i also have to hide the check box icon now on runtime.

Comment: It shows only the selected nodes, both children and parents, and hides all the others. Is it not what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

From the response above I was able to create this function that filters the Treeview based on a node attribute value. (Replace '

```
$('#jstree').find('li').each(function () {
    if ($("#" + this.id).attr("tag") == "<MYTAG>") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).show();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another code maybe help someone.

```
var value = $(this).val();
if (value == "all") {
    $('#permissions').jstree("show_all")
    return;
}
checkedNodes = $('#permissions').jstree("get_checked", true);
if (value == "granted") {
    $('#permissions').jstree("hide_all")
    checkedNodes.forEach(function (node) {
        $('#permissions').jstree("show_node", node.parent);
        $('#permissions').jstree("show_node", node);
    });
}
else if ("notgranted") {
    $('#permissions').jstree("show_all")
    checkedNodes.forEach(function (node) {
        $('#permissions').jstree("hide_node", node);
    });
}
```